# multiple regression and bootstrapping

Tags: distributions, multiple-regression, bootstrap

I performed multiple regression and some of the assumptions are violated like normality of the outcome variable. Can I use bootstrap to correct for violated assumptions? Or doing it would be pointless!

Comment: Which assumptions specifically do you believe are violated and what are you attempting to accomplish with this regression?

Comment: 2 main assumptions are violated; Non-normally distributed outcome variable and non-normally distributed residuals

Comment: Normality of the outcome (dependent) variable is never an assumption in regression (except when regressing against a constant).  But, again: *why* are you performing this procedure? For estimation, prediction, forecasting, or what?

Comment: I'm performing it mainly for estimation and somewhat for prediction

Comment: Have you searched our site for related posts?  A search on [bootstrap regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bootstrap+regression) turns up several hundred and the top hits look relevant.  Please read them over and consider how you might edit your question to give it a clearer context and focus.